# Getting Error 100% (not considered the csv file data at all) when tried to run Jmeter in non gui mode using csv files

Tags: jmeter

Getting Error 100% (not considered the csv file data at all) when tried to run Jmeter in non gui mode using csv files (`Jmeter docker container`). By looking at the `jmeter.log`, not able to figure it out the reason. Looks like the JMeter is not able to pick the `usernames` data from `csv` file hence getting these errors. If I don't use the `csv` file, able to run successfully.

Steps followed:

1. Placed csv files under bin folder of slave and master machines
2. The .jmx file has csv data set config added to the http request with Filename path as just the filename (given the filename since these csv files are already in bin folder of slaves/master machines)
3. Run the below command in master machine.

> ./jmeter -n -t xxxx.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.xx.xx.xx
>   -Dclient.rmi.localport=60000 -Ryy.yy.yy.yy,zz.zz.zz.zz -j jmeter.log -l results.csv

Please guide.

Please find attached screen shots for jmeter.log file
[image: 1]

[image]

[image: server log]

Comment: What is in the slave engine log file?

Comment: do I need to run any command to get slave engine log file? I am running the run command with -j jmeter.log in master server, no command has been run in slave machine, please let me know if slave log file can be get by running any command. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just like you run the master: `jmeter -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter-server.log`. Check out [Full list of JMeter command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) and [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Comment: Apologies..not able to get it. Do I need to run this command jmeter -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter-server.log in server machine?

Comment: This is for slave (remote machine)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. When i loaded the results.csv file in 'View results tree' can see an error as <EOF>, looks like it it is not able to fine the file. I have placed two csv files under slave machine /jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/ (this is docker container) and given the file name:usernames.csv (this way also not working), tried with (..\bin\usernames.csv-not working). Please suggest what should i give as filename.

Comment: I have added the jmeter-server.log file screen shot. please suggest.

Comment: The log file is truncated hence it doesn't tell the full story. Check out CSV Data Set Config details, in particular Sharing More, Recycle on EOF and Stop Thread on EOF settings, see [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for explanation of the above settings

Comment: @Dmitri T Thanks for all the help. Able to solve the issue by giving full jmeter slave docker container path with forward slash in csv data set config.

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve the issue by giving full jmeter slave docker container path with forward slash in csv data set config like below:
/jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/usernames.csv